# FAILED: ParseException line 5:16 cannot recognize input near 'TIME' ',' 'store_name' in column type

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am getting error when trying to create a table in hive database. I am accessing it through docker image.

The command I am using:

```
root@:/opt/Hadoop#hive -f test_db.sql
```

Below mentioned is the content for the `.sql` file:

```
create database test_db;

use test_db;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE purchases (
  
purchase_date DATE, 
  
Purchase_time TIME,
  
store_name STRING, 
  
item_name STRING,
  
item_cost FLOAT,
 
payment STRING

) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#'
STORED AS TEXTFILE

LOCATION '/user/input/purchases';
```

The error is:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 5:16 cannot recognize input near 'TIME' ',' 
'store_name' in column type
```

Any idea what's wrong in this?

Thanks!

Comment: No problem Deep 

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the 'TIME' datatype into 'TIMESTAMP' and tried building the table, I could build the table inside HIVE.

```
create database test_db;

use test_db;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE purchases (

purchase_date DATE,

Purchase_time TIMESTAMP,

store_name STRING,

item_name STRING,

item_cost FLOAT,

payment STRING

) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE

LOCATION '/user/input/purchases';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).